# Event implementation in C++ with performance in mind

Tags: c++, events, memory-management, event-handling, rule-engine

I'm creating an engine that manages events and that executes different actions depending on specific input rules.

Let's say that I have Element A that when an event arrives produces a value x. When it is produced it sends an event to the system that notifies other Elements. Once notified these elements get from the Event message the id of the sender and get the value directly from the sender, not from the Event object.

What do you think about it in terms of performance?

The other alternative is to store the Element producer computed value into the Event, but since I would like to avoid to call the new operator too many times I don't think it's a viable solution.

Even using something like:

```
struct Event
{
int idProducer;
MyEnumType type;
union Storage
  {
  uint32_t intElement;
  double doubleElement;
  void* voidElement;
  MyValueBase* baseElement;
  };
};
```

If most of the Producers use the new operator, it won't work for me.

The downside of the the first approach is probably that there might be the need to use extra mutexes.

Which solution would you choose?

[edit] I'll provide more details as requested:

there will be more threads

The structure I had in mind if using the solution with the computed value in the Executer element is:

```
// This is not the actual code but just a semplification: 
struct ExecuterBase
  {
  virtual void manageEvent(const Event& event)=0;
  virtual void addEvent(const Event& event)
    {
    eventQueue.push(event);
    }

  SharedState* state_;
  int idElement_;
  };

template<class ReturnType>
struct ExecuterBaseR : ExecuterBase 
{ 
virtual ReturnType result() = 0;
};


struct ConcreteExecuter : ExecuterBaseR<double>
{
void manageEvent(const Event& e) override
 {
 result_ = /* something computed*/;
 }

 double result() {return result_;}
};
```

Comment: To avoid costly new / delete operations, why not create a pool of items that can be filled / used when needed? Once the event has been handled, the item can be cleaned up and put back into the pool.

Comment: can be another option indeed. You mean something like: A creates X of type T and id Y. Then Consumer has to look into the pool of type T for the item of id Y. Something like this? I see however also many lookups and also copies, but it can be evaluated thanks

Comment: You might be interested in `polymorphic_memory_resource`s which have been included in c++17 and are available in boost: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/container/cpp_conformance.html#container.cpp_conformance.polymorphic_memory_resources

Comment: interesting, I'll have a read. How about those two solutions I proposed, which one do you prefer?

Comment: Your question is very broad, so can you add some more details? For instance the absence of multiple threads would simplify your task dramatically.